# Apple-provided environment var `dismissSearch` not working

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

In this SwiftUI-based code, the dismissSearch, as specified [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismisssearch), does not work.
That is, upon tapping "Search" on the keyboard, I expected the search bar to cancel, clear the search text field, and have the nav bar with the gear icon *visible*. As you can see in the GIF below, the keyboard disappears (expected) but the search bar neither clears the text nor "cancels".

Do note that a print out of `disappearSearch` prints `DismissSearchAction(state: nil)`.

What could be going on?

```
struct GroceryListView2: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch
    @State private var searchQuery = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hi")
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                        Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "gear")})
                )
                .searchable(
                    text: $searchQuery,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .automatic),
                    prompt: "Add or search"
                )
                .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                    print("onSubmit", dismissSearch) // DismissSearchAction(state: nil)
                    dismissSearch()
                }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. You have stumbled on some really weird behavior:

- The `@Environment(\.dismissSearch)` property doesn't get populated with a useful value if it's in the same `View` that applies the `.searchable` modifier. My guess is `searchable` is responsible for putting the `DismissSearchAction` in the environment.
- The `onSubmit` modifier doesn't work if it's applied inside (before) the `searchable` modifier. My guess is `onSubmit` stores the callback in the environment for `searchable` to read.

This leads to needing a convoluted view structure where you apply `onSubmit` outside (after) the `searchable` modifier and have it set an `@State` property which you pass down as a `Binding` and read in an `onChange` modifier on your inner view, where you have the `@Environment(\.dismissSearch)` property available.

I've wrapped it all up into a handy modifier, `searchableOnce`, which is like `searchable` but dismisses on submit. Here's how your code looks with this modifier:

```
struct GroceryListView2: View {
    @State private var searchQuery = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hi")
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                        Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "gear")})
                )
                .searchableOnce(
                    text: $searchQuery,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .automatic),
                    prompt: "Add or search"
                )
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the modifier implementation:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
extension SwiftUI.View {
  public func searchableOnce(text: SwiftUI.Binding<Swift.String>, placement: SwiftUI.SearchFieldPlacement = .automatic, prompt: SwiftUI.Text? = nil) -> some SwiftUI.View {
      return SearchableOnce(content: self, text: text, placement: placement, prompt: prompt)
  }

  public func searchableOnce(text: SwiftUI.Binding<Swift.String>, placement: SwiftUI.SearchFieldPlacement = .automatic, prompt: SwiftUI.LocalizedStringKey) -> some SwiftUI.View {
      return SearchableOnce(content: self, text: text, placement: placement, prompt: Text(prompt))
  }

  @_disfavoredOverload public func searchableOnce<S>(text: SwiftUI.Binding<Swift.String>, placement: SwiftUI.SearchFieldPlacement = .automatic, prompt: S) -> some SwiftUI.View where S : Swift.StringProtocol {
      return SearchableOnce(content: self, text: text, placement: placement, prompt: Text(prompt))
  }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
fileprivate struct SearchableOnce<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var wantDismiss = false
    var content: Content
    var text: Binding<String>
    var placement: SearchFieldPlacement
    var prompt: Optional<Text>

    var body: some View {
        Dismisser(wantDismiss: $wantDismiss, content: content)
            .searchable(text: text, placement: placement, prompt: prompt)
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                wantDismiss = true
            }
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
fileprivate struct Dismisser<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch
    @Binding var wantDismiss: Bool
    var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: wantDismiss) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    dismissSearch()
                    wantDismiss = false
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting...
would you be able to make searchableOnce accept a `suggestions` a là `.searchable`?

Comment: If you mean the [`searchable` modifier that has a `suggestedTokens` parameter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/searchable(text:tokens:suggestedtokens:placement:prompt:token:)-9m40k), I think you should be able to modify my code to wrap that version without too much difficulty.